# transform: scaleX() seems to change element's height

Tags: css, scale, css-transforms, css-grid

I hope someone can help me out. I have one div in a CSS grid that I want to expand neatly along the x axis when hovered over. I used transform: scaleX() to that end, but I'm noticing something very annoying: after the animation finishes playing, on certain viewport heights, the expanded element either grows or shrinks by 1 pixel. This problem doesn't occur if I give the div a static height like 200px, but I don't want to do that. Does anyone know why this is happening, and how best to resolve it? Must I ditch transform altogether, and do something like transition: width instead?

```
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

body > div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.green {
  background-color: #090;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.green:hover {
  transform: scaleX(2);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
 }
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Art365/pen/WKXPRw)

Screenshot of the problem (only occurs on certain window heights):
[image]

Comment: this is happening because of `grid-gap: 1px` as it scaling will start from right after the div is end, but there is a gap of 1px which is between 2 grid boxes, so the hovered element keeps short by 1px in covering both the grid boxes.
Put `grid-gap:0px` and see if this is what you want.

Comment: Alas, no. I got rid of the grid-gap and it still manages to shrink by 1 pixel, exposing the black background underneath.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a perfect `1/3` could exist in CSS, in your case you are using `1fr`. The `fr` unit creates flexible grid tracks. It represents a fraction of the available space in the grid container, this creates the issue of fractional pixels.

Fractional pixels - When the elements are displayed on the screen, most browsers will naturally round the position to the nearest pixel, as per your css onhover you will notice that fractional pixel value difference.

You can read this article to know more about it - [Sub-Pixel Problems in CSS](https://johnresig.com/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/)

I personally would do add pixel height to fix the issue :)

Comment: Please have a look at this pen https://codepen.io/girish/full/qyxaWd/, that issue will still exist in some cases, but i am using `percentage` values instead of `fr` units. hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I guess there's no way to salvage transform scale in this case, and I'll probably just go with transitioning length. That works, for some reason.